# MVC&EF: remove time from datetime

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, datetime

I have a model that contains a datetime field.
The column in the DB which it prepresents is of datatype 'date', so it has no time value.
The model date field is bound to a  jquery-ui datepicker in my view.
When the page loads, it has time value: 1989/02/14 12:00:00 AM
How can I prevent the time value from being added?
Do I have to manually strip out the time portion with jQuery for every date field?

**EDIT:**
There is no point in editing the model, when the page loads its still there

Controller:

```
ClientModel c = DBContext.Clients.find(id);
//Doing any kind of date formatting here to c.DateOfBirth is ignored
return PartialView("_ClientDetailsView", c);
```

View:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DateOfBirth , new { @class = "date-field" })
```

I'm thinking that the solution would be something like a model attribute or a HtmlHelper parameter.

Comment: You can stored it in your database using right(jquerytime, 10)

Comment: insert into table(mydate) values(right(jquerytime, 10));

Comment: See Edit section above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the help Henk

In the end I grew tired of trying to find a 'proper' solution so I wrote the following jquery function and calling it on each page as required.

```
function DropTimeSegments() {
$(".datepicker").each(function (index, item) {
    $(item).val(FormatDate(new Date($(item).val())));
});

function FormatDate(Date) {
    return Date.getFullYear() + '-' + pad(Date.getMonth(), 2) + '-' + pad(Date.getDate(), 2);
}

function pad(num, size) {
    var s = num + "";
    while (s.length < size) s = "0" + s;
    return s;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`DataType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.datatypeattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute for this. Decorate your `DateOfBirth` property in the `ClientModel` with it:

```
public class ClientModel
{
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
}
```

Also see the [`DataType` enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.datatype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

---

You can also use the [`DisplayFormat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayformatattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute if you the `DataType` attribute doesn't fit your needs:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "dd MM, yyyy")]    
public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
```

Comment: i just tested this, and still no joy.